# sshd: unrecognized service

Tags: ssh, centos6

I am trying to start sshd but i am getting an error which says

```
sshd: unrecognized service
```

However, it seems that sshd is installed properly (?)

```
# rpm -qa | grep ssh
libssh2-1.4.2-2.el6_7.1.x86_64
openssh-5.3p1-117.el6.x86_64
openssh-clients-5.3p1-117.el6.x86_64

# which sshd
/usr/sbin/sshd
```

is there something that i need to do for service to recognize sshd?
i see this in /etc as well

```
# ls /etc/ssh
moduli       sshd_config           ssh_host_key      ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
ssh_config   ssh_host_dsa_key      ssh_host_key.pub
sshd-banner  ssh_host_dsa_key.pub  ssh_host_rsa_key
```

Comment: is there an explanation for downvote? im trying to understand why im seeing that error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't seem to have the `openssh-server` RPM installed. That is the RPM that provides both `/usr/sbin/sshd` and `/etc/init.d/sshd` - and the latter script must exist for the `service sshd ...` command to work.

Why you seem to have `/usr/sbin/sshd` without the `openssh-server` RPM, I don't know.

Comment: thank you i installed openssh-server and i can service sshd start